# Get first level of object length count from JSON in js

Tags: javascript, json

I currently have a stringify JSON object that is like this:
(Important, it's an object that I have to stringify and AFTER I need the length count)

I'm doing a call on a database which returns `result`.
I think wrap my result like so : `var myData = JSON.stringify(result);`

This produces the following, a lot more of it though:

```
myData =   {
    "0":[{"id": 50, "product_id": 'blah blah', etc}, {"id": 52, "product_id": 'blah blah', etc}, {"id": 50, "product_id": 'blah blah', etc}],
    "1":[{"id": 50, "product_id": 'blah blah', etc}, {"id": 52, "product_id": 'blah blah', etc}, {"id": 50, "product_id": 'blah blah', etc}],
    "2":[{"id": 50, "product_id": 'blah blah', etc}, {"id": 52, "product_id": 'blah blah', etc}, {"id": 50, "product_id": 'blah blah', etc}]
}
```

I've tried everything I can think of to get the length of the root level.  In this example there would be 3. I need to know the length so I can run a loop through it selecting each one.

How can I do this?

I've tried for `(var data in myData)` and I've tried `Object.keys(myData).length`.

I've console logged `Ojbect.keys(myData).length` and the result is `9234`.

Nothing I've tried seems to work.

Comment: Sorry I fixed it, this is how it actually is, my bad @NickParsons

Comment: I don't see any JSON in this question. "doesn't work" is not a problem description. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Both of the things you say you tried should work to count keys, so please show how you tried them.

Comment: @melpomene he specifically said _after_ he calls `stringify` on it, which I assume means `JSON.stringify`

Comment: @FabricioG are you not able to use the reverse, `JSON.parse` and then use `Object.keys().length`?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst How would knowing the length help with looping through a JSON string?

Comment: `Object.keys(myData).length` does return 3. If myData is a stringified JSON, JSON.parse then.

Comment: @melpomene the question he is asking is: how do I calculate how many values are at the root key in a stringified JSON object?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst The question I am asking is: How would that be useful for looping through a stringified object?

Comment: I hadn't tried JSON.parse let me try that @MatthewHerbst

Comment: @melpomene why does that matter? Why someone wants to do something doesn't impact if the question is valid or not.

Comment: I need to find the count because it's going to run another script based upon the "group".  Specifically it's json going to a program called Illustrator which needs the data to be a json string to run then I need to count the group to create an artboard on each one.  @MatthewHerbst

Comment: @FabricioG yeah, that will solve your issue: `const length = Object.keys(JSON.parse(jsonData)).length` where `jsonData` is the value returned to you by the server.

Comment: Just don't call `JSON.stringify` in the first place (or rather, only call `JSON.stringify` at the end when you need a string; do all your main work on the real object).

Comment: It has to be a string... Flow is js to jsx and it requires a json string.  It's CEP -> JSX adobe, is the workflow @melpomene

Comment: @melpomene you assuming he has access to JSON object in his context.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst worked like a charm, THANK YOU!

Comment: please do first => https://jsonlint.com/ your json is invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guess I'll add it as an answer :)

The data you are getting from the server is in JSON format since you wrapped it with `JSON.stringify`. Now you need to parse the data first before you can do much with it. Use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to do this:

```
const serverJSONResponse = getJSONFromServer();
const myData = JSON.parse(serverJSONResponse);
const length = Object.keys(myData).length;
```

Do note that there are ways of telling whatever you're using on the client to make the request that the response will be JSON, and then it will automatically call `JSON.parse` for you so that you don't need to manually do it every time.

Answer (score 2):

`Object.keys(myData).length)` works perfectly

```js
    var myData = {
      "0": [
        { "id": 50, "product_id": "blah blah",  "etc" : 44 },
        { "id": 52, "product_id": "blah blah", "etc" : 44  },
        { "id": 50, "product_id": "blah blah", "etc" : 44  }
      ],
      "1": [
        { "id": 50, "product_id": "blah blah",  "etc" : 44 },
        { "id": 52, "product_id": "blah blah", "etc" : 44  },
        { "id": 50, "product_id": "blah blah", "etc" : 44  }
      ],
      "2": [
        { "id": 50, "product_id": "blah blah",  "etc" : 44 },
        { "id": 52, "product_id": "blah blah", "etc" : 44  },
        { "id": 50, "product_id": "blah blah", "etc" : 44  }
      ] 
    }



    console.log(Object.keys(myData).length) //  => 3
```

Comment: I have no idea who marked you down, or why.